# why does this class return variable not found?

Tags: php, class

Why am i getting

```
Undefined variable: req
```

When i have declared the property at the top of my class:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class Disqus_ApiService extends BaseApplicationComponent
{
    private $req = false;

    public function init()
    {
        $d = craft()->plugins->getPlugin('disqus');
        $settings = $d->getSettings();
        $this->$req = new \DisqusAPI($settings['DISQUS_SECRET_KEY']);
    }

    public function trends()
    {
      return $this->req->trends;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$this->req` is not the same as `$this->$req`

Comment: yes i see the answer below... man i dont see how i didnt see it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
$this->req
```

Instead of

```
$this->$req
```

In

```
$this->$req = new \DisqusAPI($settings['DISQUS_SECRET_KEY']);
```

Comment: wow fast. Won't let me accept the answer yet, need to wait lol.